# How to delay to assign a value to a val in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I define mContext as val and I need to assign a value to it in the fun onCreate.

The code `private lateinit val mContext: Context` isn't correct, how can I do?

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mContext: Context

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        mContext = this
    }
}
```

**Answer Strelok**

The keyword `this` isn't always fit, just like the following code, so I think it's more handier to assign `this` to mContext.

```
 private Context mContext;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        mContext=this;

        findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello B", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Hello C", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Doesn't work
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need to set mContext to this in the first place?

Comment: Thanks! I need use mConext in other functions, so I need to assign a value to mContext onCreate function

Comment: @HelloCW but why not just use `this` when you want to use it in another function. So strange.

Comment: @HelloCW Get rid of that bad habit asap.

Comment: @Strelok I think @HelloCW doesn't know about qualified this -> `this@UIMain` for more see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `lateinit` keyword, you'll have to change from `val` to `var`, thus losing the immutability. If that's ok for you, Strelok's answer will suffice.

But if you really need a `val` on your code for any reason, you can try the [lazy delagate property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy).

As stated on the [Android Essense](https://androidessence.com/android/understanding-nullability-in-kotlin/) blog:

> This property takes in a lambda, **which is executed the first time the
>   property is accessed**. After that, it will return the value that was
>   assigned to it. This way we can declare the property as immutable, and
>   non-null, so that as long as the fragment (or Activity) is created before we access it the first time.

For example, in your case you could try to do this:

```
private val mContext : Context by lazy {
    this
}
```

**In short:**

- If your value can or need to be mutable, use `lateinit`
- If your value is meant to be initialized once, and shared across your methods, use `lazy` with `val`.

But as stated by the others, in your specific case it's better to just call `this` when you need the Activity/Context reference.

**Edit:** As per your example on why you would need a `mContext` inside your Activity, I still say you don't need it.

Instead of trying to call `this` and use it on the `Toast#makeText()` inside your anonymous function directly, you could either:

- Change `this` to `UIMain.this`.
- Create a method inside your Activity, and call that method inside the anonymous function. e.g.: `findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener { otherMethod() }`, and inside that method you can reference the Activity using `this` again.

Comment: Yes that's right, but if you wanted to set the property later after some action is done (like onCreate is called), this obviously wouldn't work. But thanks to OP's more than strange design, this is probably better :D I just want to hear why he wants to do this :D

Comment: Yeah, it's weird indeed :D I'm curious why he want to do that. But he does have some alternatives that doesn't involve keeping that context inside an Activity, since he can access it using `this`.

Comment: Thanks! To Mauker: Do you mean that somtimes your code will cause the APP crash?

Comment: No, I didn’t say that. Did it crash for you?

Comment: Strelok said " but if you wanted to set the property later after some action is done (like onCreate is called), this obviously wouldn't work.  ", so I think maybe your code will cause an app crash.

Comment: And more, I add some content for  the question, and answer why I need assign this to mContext.

Comment: In the example you provided, you could call a method inside your Activity instead of trying to display the toast inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want is a **qualified this expression** like

```
this@UIMain
```

as in

```
Toast.makeText(this@UIMain, "Hello C", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //works everytime
```

that solves all your issues. See [Kotlin this expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

PS: If that solves your problem you should rename the question to "how to use outer this in nested object"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the person commenting, it's rather strange why you want to keep a reference to `this` in a private property (potential memory leak).

But, in any case, Kotlin has a `lateinit` modifier that let's you delay setting a property value, but it must be set before the property is used for the first time.

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        mContext = this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that mContext should be val

Comment: It is a theoretical impossibility to create memory leak by assigning a property to `this`. Just think about it for a second.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please see my modified question?

Answer (score 1):

We have never liked Toast even with jelly Here is a way to replace that little slice of toast with a custom visible error message. Yes we included the toast since the question is about Toast. To use this concept you need to add a TextView some where on your screen. This code is testing for valid entry in two EditText fields.

```
    fun onLAMmultiply(view: View ){

    if(etValOne.text.length == 0){
        error("Enter First Value")
        toast("Enter First Value TOAST")
        etValOne.requestFocus()
        return@onLAMmultiply
    }

    if(etValTwo.text.length == 0){
        error("Enter Second Value")
        toast("Enter Second Value TOAST")
        etValTwo.requestFocus()
        return@onLAMmultiply
    }

    var X = etValOne.text.toString()
    var Y = etValTwo.text.toString()
    val multB = {X:Double,Y:Double -> X.times(Y)}
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
    //val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()))
    etANS.setText(df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble())).toString())
    etANS.setText(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()).toString())

}

fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun error(msg:String){
    object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            tvError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tvError.setText(msg)
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            tvError.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            tvError.setText("")
        }
    }.start()
}
```